# Dropdownlistfor always first value selected while batch editing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm  trying to batch edit multiple rows where I use a list with status among others to edit.

However, my list won't set the correct value for each row, insted it always chooses the first item in the list. I'm clueless why and asking if anyone knows why and what the solution is.

This happens only while batch editing and not in any other single row editing view. Difference is I'm looping through a list to set and render the values. Just to be extra clear :)

Thanks in advance!

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult BatchEdit(string search, int organization)
{
    var products = _classService.Get(search, organization);
    var statusList = _productService.GetStatus();

    var batchEditViewModel = new BatchEditViewModel(products, statusList);

    return View("BatchEdit", batchEditViewModel);
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public BatchEditViewModel(List<Product> products, List<ProductStatus> productStatus)
{
    Products = products;
    ProductStatus = SetStatus(productStatus);
}
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProductStatus { get; set; }

private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SetStatus(IEnumerable<ProductStatus> productStatus)
{
    return new SelectList(productStatus, "Id", "Title");
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Products)
{
   <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
       <label>Status</label>
       @Html.DropDownListFor(m => item.StatusId, Model.ProductStatus, new { @class = "form-control" })
   </div>
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: do you set **`m => m.Product.StatusId`** before executing `return View(Model)`?

Comment: @MaximilianAst Yes I do :) Updated question with controller, forgot to add it.

Comment: where do you define `Product` I can only find `Products`

Comment: @MaximilianAst I didn't want to bloat the whole post so i skipped it. Update question with aleast the foreach :)

Answer (score 1):

in `item.Product.StatusId`

`item` is already a `Product` so try:

```
item.StatusId
```

instead of

```
item.Product.StatusId
```

Comment: Sorry, It's my fault. I accidentally put it there. It's like you said but still won't work :/

Answer (score 1):

Solved by doing like this insted:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => item.StatusId, new SelectList(Model.ProductStatus, "Value", "Text", item.StatusId), new { @class = "form-control status-select" })
```

Comment: Seems logical. I totally overlooked. :)

Comment: @MaximilianAst I highly appreciate all the suggestions/help I got from you, thanks mate :)